C++: preserve const-ness of a template template parameter
A reference template parameter is deduced to be const or non-const depending on the argument. A reference template template parameter always ends up being non-const. Is there a way to fix it?
#include <concepts>
#include <print>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, std::invocable<T> Visitor>
void ref_visit(T& t, const Visitor& visit) { visit(t); }

template<template<typename> typename C, typename T, std::invocable<T> Visitor>
void template_ref_visit(C<T>& c, Visitor visit) { visit(c[0]); }

struct Printer {
    void operator()(int& i) const { std::println("non-const: {}", i); }
    void operator()(const int& i) const { std::println("const: {}", i); }
} printer;

int main()
{
    int i{1};
    int& ri{i};
    const int& cri{i};
    ref_visit(ri, printer); // prints "non-const: 1"
    ref_visit(cri, printer); // prints "const: 1"

    std::vector<int> v{42};
    std::vector<int>& rv{v};
    const std::vector<int>& crv{v};
    template_ref_visit(rv, printer); // prints "non-const: 42"
    template_ref_visit(crv, printer); // FAILS TO COMPILE
}

Compiler output:
template_template_const.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
template_template_const.cpp:29:24: error: binding reference of type ‘std::vector<int>&’ to ‘const std::vector<int>’ discards qualifiers
   29 |     template_ref_visit(crv, printer); // FAILS TO COMPILE
      |                        ^~~
template_template_const.cpp:10:31: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void template_ref_visit(C<T>&, Visitor) [with C = std::vector; T = int; Visitor = Printer]’
   10 | void template_ref_visit(C<T>& c, Visitor visit) { visit(c[0]); }
      |

Adding an overload
template<template<typename> typename C, typename T, std::invocable<T> Visitor>
void template_ref_visit(const C<T>& c, Visitor visit) { visit(c[0]); }

leads to code duplication. Can it be avoided?

You add an overload template<template<typename> typename C, typename T> const C<T>& template_ref_passthrough(const C<T>& c) { return c; } just as always when dealing with conditional-const references in function parameters where the const affects the function semantics.

Re: why. T can be deduced as int or const int - both are types.  But C can't be deducted as const std::vector, because const std::vector is not a thing that exists. Re: what to do. In this particular example, you don't need template template parameter in the first place; ref_passthrough would work in place of template_ref_passthrough. If you have an example where you believe you do need template template parameter, show it.

An overload would require duplicating the entire function. I need access to T inside of C<T>. Changed example to reflect this.

Instead of deducing T as a template parameter, you can derive it from the type of some expression.  Example

Did exactly that.

T in std::vector<T> can be accessed through value_type:
template<typename C, typename T = C::value_type, std::invocable<T> Visitor>
void template_ref_visit(C& c, Visitor& visit) { visit(c[0]); }


Since you are using C++20 going by the concept use: There is a generalization of ::value_type that works on all kinds of ranges, not only containers: std::ranges::range_value_t. From what you are showing now it seems that it would make sense for your to make use of the ranges interfaces in general. This template can then constrain C to with std::ranges::range as well.

std::vector was used as an example, I'm not really dealing with a range. Just some class holding a T inside of it. I've updated it to have a T typedef inside of it just like std::vector.
